# Как такое возможно

Tags: массивы, reactjs

Использую react typescript
сначала через консоль вывожу сам массив, затем его размер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот что показывает консоль, если выводить массив, то его размер 3, а если выводить его длинну, то размер 1, как такое возможно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в синенькую букву i на вашем скрине

Comment: она не нажимается

Comment: просто мышку наведите

Answer (score 1):

Когда в консоль выводится число, оно просто печатается. Если вывести длину массива, а затем изменить массив, длина в консоли останется неизменной.

Напротив, когда выводится массив, консоль сохраняет ссылку на массив. Если позже массив изменится, вы увидите изменения массива в консоли.

Так устроена консоль. Если нужно вывести состояние массива или объекта в определённый момент, так что бы позже он не поменялся, используйте трюк из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects):

> Don't use `console.log(obj)`, use
> `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))`
>
> This way you are sure you are seeing the value of `obj` at the moment
> you log it. Otherwise, many browsers provide a live view that
> constantly updates as values change. This may not be what you want.

Вот [перевод](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log#%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), пусть и ужасный:

> Не используйте `console.log(obj);`, Используйте
> `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));`.
>
> Так вы можете быть уверены, что видите значение `obj` в момент, его
> логирования.